# How to extract a string between a symbol and a space?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to extract usernames tagged in a text-chat, such as "@Jack @Marie Hi there!"

I am trying to do it on the combination of @ and whitespace but I cannot get the regex to match non-greedy (or at least this is what I think is wrong):

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string = '@This is what I want to extract', pattern = "(?<=@)(.*)(?=\\s+)")

[1] "This is what I want to"
```

What I would like to extract instead is only `This`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your regex non greedy:

[`(?<=@)(.*?)(?=\s+)`](https://regex101.com/r/tGLj7H/1)

Or if you want to capture only "This" after the `@` sign, you could try it like this using only a positive lookbehind:

[`(?<=@)\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/lqWlPh/1)

**Explanation**

- A positive lookbehind `(?<=`
- That asserts that what is behind is an `@`
- Close positive lookbehind `)`
- Match one or more word characters `\w+`

Answer (score 3):

The central part of your regex (`(.*)`) is a sequence of any chars.

Instead you shoud look for a sequence of chars other than white space
(`\S+`) or *word chars* (`\w+`).

Note also that I changed `*` to `+`, as you are probably not interested
in any empty sequence of chars.

To capture also a name which has "last" position in the source
string, the last part of your regex should match not only a sequence
of whitespace chars, but also the end of the string, so change
`(?=\\s+)` to `(?=\\s+|$)`.

And the last remark: Actually you don't need the parentheses around
the "central" part.

So to sum up, the whole regex can be like this:

```
(?<=@)\w+(?=\s+|$)
```

(with *global* oprion).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non-regex approach or rather a minimal-regex approach since `grep` takes the detection of `@` through the regex engine

```
grep('@', strsplit(x, ' ')[[1]], value = TRUE)
#[1] "@This"
```

Or to avoid `strsplit`, we can use `scan` (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46240282/5635580)), i.e.

```
grep('@', scan(textConnection(x), " "), value=TRUE)
#Read 7 items
#[1] "@This"
```